# The xcode iOS Simulator is prompting me to "choose the folder containing the iOS Simulator SDK" on open. How do I find it?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2, ios-simulator

I just installed xcode for the first time and I opened the iOS simulator.  When I do it is requiring me to first "Please choose the folder containing the iOS Simulator SDK" and I have no idea how to located this.  Does anyone know where it is?  All I went to do is start testing some mobile websites.

Comment: Open Xcode preferences and go to the downloads tab, under "Components" which Simulators does Xcode say are there?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the latest Xcode from the app store it should have installed the sdk and set it up for you. You could try reinstalling if this is how you got it, but check my next comment first...

If you installed Xcode some other way, it may not have come with an sdk. You can check in preferences>Downloads to see if you can download it there (I don't remember if you can) or try the website: https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice to look in Preferences | Downloads and the installer was there. It looks like an updated Xcode doesn't include device simulators by default.